# Node.js Error - 'Cannot use import outside of a module'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ecmascript-6, import

I am working on a React Project, and I have...

> Firebase.js

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
export const database = firebase.database()
```

> Server.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const { database } = require('../firebase/firebase')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public')

app.use(express.static(publicDir))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/someRoute', (req, res) => {
    // Wanna send data to database using 'database'
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on PORT...', port)
})
```

Now, I just wanna save Data to Database on '/someRoute' but it is giving me an error : 'cannot use import outside module'

Comment: I think the error is due to the firebase folder being outside the root of the project. Make sure that you are not importing anything that is outside the package.json folder

Comment: Nope , the firebase file is inside Project Folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import {} from XXX` is not supported initially from NodeJS. So you should either use

- `const XXX = require()`-syntax or
- `type: module` in your `package.json`.

The same is for exports: in Node, you can use `module.exports = YOUR_FUNCTION_OR_CLASS`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding
**"type" : "module"**
to your package.json.
You can also change your file extension from **.js** to **.mjs**